# Manually setting task's try number in Airflow

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

As the title says, in my operator, inside of its execute() method, I would like to do something like

```
if some_condition():
  self.try_number = 0
```

Because I want Airflow to forget about the previous failures. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not advise modifying try numbers since it would be difficult to debug in the future. But if you want to give it a try why don't you access the `task_instance` object and modify the parameters `try_number` or `with_try_number`?

I believe the latter lets you return your task with a given try number

Comment: I decided to manually implement retry logic inside of my operator, throwing AirflowFailException when necessary.